# Azure Python SDK: BlobServiceClient.get_container_client returning TypeError?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk

This is baffling me. I must be missing something obvious. Just trying to get a `ContainerClient` from a `BlobServiceClient`.

**Example:**

```
import os
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient

conn_string = "connection-string-here"
cont_name = "cont-test"

blob_svc_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_string)

blob_cont_client = BlobServiceClient.get_container_client(cont_name)
```

**Returns:**

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>python myProgram.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\myProgram.py", line 11, in <module>
    blob_cont_client = BlobServiceClient.get_container_client(cont_name)
TypeError: get_container_client() missing 1 required positional argument: 'container'
```

- But `get_container_client()` is not missing the positionaly argument 'container'.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code by adding the extension to blob_svc_client with get_container_client variable.
Below is the updated code:

```
import os
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient

conn_string = "connection-string-here"
cont_name = "cont-test"

blob_svc_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_string)

blob_cont_client = blob_svc_client.get_container_client(cont_name)
```

I have reproduced your error as below:

[image: Error]

Below is the fixed screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight! I was staring at that code for too long to see the issue!